# what's the meaning of 'we'll go out when it stops raining.'?

Tags: grammar, questions

> we'll go out when it stops raining.

I wonder the meaning and usage of 'will' at this sentence.

I think it's not predicting but offering (meaning 'shall we go out when it stops raining?').

Am I correct?

Comment: Without further context I don't see why _we will go out..._ would mean _shall we go out...?_. Maybe _with_ some context it would be clearer.

Comment: The sentence is a simple statement of intention. Depending on context (perhaps a promised outing with a child has fallen victim to the weather), it could be seen as an implied offer, but that has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: As mentioned above, context is everything here. The sentence is correct and meaningful, but exactly what it means is unclear. Just putting a question mark on the end, for example, would change the meaning and in this case, it could easily mean 'shall we go out...'.

Answer (score 1):

*Will* refers to things that are expected to happen in the future.

The speaker expects it to stop raining in the future.

When you want something, you typically don't have it yet (otherwise you wouldn't be talking about wanting it), but it's something you want to have in the future.  So logically *will* works for intentions and commands.

You are right in that it's ambiguous.

We don't really know if the the speaker is *wanting* to go out when it stops raining, or if someone/something is going to *make* them move outside when it stops raining.  Previous sentences would reveal that.

To disambiguate:

> I { want us to | hope that we } go out when it stops raining (this is what I want to do when it stops raining.)
>
> We'll be moving out when it stops raining (someone/thing else will make us move when the rain stops.)

Answer (score 0):

"**will**" here is intended to introduce an action that is to occure in the future. Without context this action can either be forced or done by free will.